Set type of return key(s) from value(s) appearing in a passed Array
I am writing an api-library and have an interface where certain keys can change depending on what is presented during the request, i.e if certain parameters are added, a key can change from a string type to an object type:
interface MyObject {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

interface MyAddress {
  street: string;
  state: string;
  country: string;
}

interface MyPerson {
  id: string;
  personalDetails: string | MyObject;
  address: string | MyAddress;
}

type ExpandableFields = 'address' | 'personalDetails';

Lets say the user calls library.person.get(), they should get:
{
  "id": "id_123456",
  "personalDetails": "id_7890123",
  "address": "id_4567890"
}

However, if they call library.person.get({ expand: ['personalDetails', 'address'] })
They should get:
{
  "id": "id_123456",
  "personalDetails": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "email": "joe@shmo.com"
  },
  "address": {
    "street": "fake st",
    "state": "Fake",
    "Country": "FK"
  }
}

If I try to do this with just a Union, when I go to get personalDetails.name, I get the error that "name" does not exist on type "string".  If there were only 2 properties with this, I would just type check before sending the response and type the response appropriately.  However, there are 6 possible fields that can do this, and any combination of those 6, which would make it quite messy to try to type correctly when sending back.
So my question: is there a way to check if a specific field exists in the expand array passed, and then add/change the types in the interface based on what is passed? I thought of starting an interface without those fields and then adding them based on what the args were:
interface MyPerson {
  id: string;
}

interface MyPersonWithAddressId extends MyPerson {
  address: string;
}

interface MyPersonWithAddress extends MyPerson {
  address: MyAddress
}

But, as mentioned, this would be way too messy to do with 6 properties and all of their possible combinations.

Is the unexpanded type always string or something else? If so you could do something like the typings shown at this playground link. If not, please [edit] to give some indication for how you'd identify the different behaviors. Anyway, if this meets your needs I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz thank you so much for this.  the unexpanded type is always string, but there are only specific values you are able to expand (added above).  in this instance, only address and personalDetails are allowed values to be expanded.

Does that change my potential answer significantly? You can just limit K to that as shown here. How should I proceed? Should I write up an answer or am I missing something?

@jcalz this makes a ton of sense, thank you so much. please do write up the answer.  I still see the error, but because I did not include the complete code here and just an example, I think there might be some tinkering I need to do.  The get method here is in an extended class and the method I am calling from super is expecting a <Return, Args> type when calling it.  I can add that to the original post as well.

@jcalz I was doing something wrong on the client end, your code worked flawlessly. thank you so so much

I assume that we only care about typings and not about implementation. One approach is to make get() generic in the type K of the elements of expand (which should be constrained to ExpandableFields), and then map over the properties P of MyPerson and either Exclude or Extract string from the union depending on whether or not P is part of K.  Like this:
interface Person {
    get<K extends ExpandableFields = never>(
        opts?: { expand: K[] }
    ): { [P in keyof MyPerson]:
            P extends K ? Exclude<MyPerson[P], string> : Extract<MyPerson[P], string>
        };
}

declare const library: { person: Person }

Then you can verify that it behaves as expected:
const a = library.person.get()
/* const a: {
    id: string;
    personalDetails: string;
    address: string;
} */

const b = library.person.get({ expand: ['personalDetails', 'address'] })
/* const b: {
    id: string;
    personalDetails: MyObject;
    address: MyAddress;
} */

And this should scale well to six or more properties.
Playground link to code

this is perfect, thank you so much.  just for my learning, if the value could also be null, would I just add that as a union as so: Extract<MyPerson[P], string|null>?

Probably, although then you might still want Exclude<MyPerson[P], string> since you don't want to exclude null. It really depends on use cases not presented here.

Would a viable alternative be having a separate field on MyPerson for addressId and detailsId?
Otherwise I you could possibly add a check and use type assertions to be explicit about what type you're returning.
if (expand.includes('address')) {
  return address as MyAddress
}
return address as string

I think you would have to do that on the "client" side though assuming I understand the situation.
Typescript - Type Assertions

I agree this would most likely have to be done by the client, but I was hoping there was a cleaner way to do it from the back end before it even gets there.  The type check would cause for a messy implementation if i was to do it on the library side.
